# Cypher hangs, how do we fix/redesign?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j, cypher

Let there be nodes m, n, p and relations r1, r2 as follows:

```
(n)-r1->(p)<-r2-(m)
```

We need to return properties from m, n, p, r1 and r2 so we have a cypher that has following START, MATCH and WHERE clause:

```
START START n=node:...
MATCH (n)-[r1:RELTYPE]->(p)<-[r2:RELTYPE]-(m)
WHERE r1.SOMEPROPERTY = r2.SOMEPROPERTY
RETURN ...
```

SOMEPROPERTY always exists on r1 and r2. Typically, n has 50,000 relations with p, and each p can have a million relations with m. We can only start at n.

The cypher hangs !! through java program and neoclipse. If we reduce the number of relations from 50,000 and 1 million down to few hundreds the cypher works.

Any suggestions on how to make this cypher algorithmically efficient, and work for large number of relations ? Also open to redesigning the graph.

Answer (score 1):

So you have |r1| = 50,000 and |r2| = 1,000,000. If you want to compare each r1 against each r2, you have 50,000 * 1,000,000 = 50,000,000,000. 50 BILLION comparisons you need to make. If each comparison takes 1 ms, it's still going to take you 50,000,000 (fifty million) seconds to perform this comparison. This is 578 days.

The only possible way I can see you reducing this complexity would be if you were to create a r1 and r2 map on node p keyed on SOMEPROPERTY. Then you would just need to get the list of r1 for SOMEPROPERTY and the list of r2 by SOMEPROPERTY.

Comment: To keep the mapping and update it everything something change is a solution. Can we do better ? Would throwing in an index for relations by the SOMEPROPERTY help ?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a much better solution than a pair of maps, with respect to time complexity. The root of the problem is how to reduce the number of comparisons. With a map, you are just retrieving two lists. As you add relationships, you do a single calculation on your P node, leaving you with M + N calculations. That's the smallest set of calculations you're going to reach.